# What's difference between "$f$ is continuous on a metric space" and "$f:(X,d)\to (Y,p), f$ is continuous"

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, terminology

There are two functions:

$f_1$ is continuous on a metric space $(X,d)$

$f_2 : (X,d)\rightarrow (Y,p) $ and $f$ is continuous.

Is there any difference between these two functions? Anything we need to be careful with when we deal with these two functions?

Comment: I think the first function is supposed to be interpreted as $f_1 : (X,d) \to (X,d)$ because continuous functions are defined so that the preimage of open sets in the range is open in the domain. I don't think it makes sense to not specify the range of the function when talking about its continuity.

Comment: @user2825632. It is common usage that "f is a function on S" means that f:S\to S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement "$f_1$ is continuous on a metric space $(X,d)$" is ambiguous and its meaning may vary based on context.  In many contexts, it means the same as your statement about $f_2$: it means that $f_1$ is a continuous function from $(X,d)$ to some other (unspecified) metric space $(Y,p)$.  It may also have a more general meaning: it might mean that $f_1$ is a continuous function from $(X,d)$ to some unspecified *topological* space, which need not be a metric space.

In other contexts, "$f_1$ is continuous on a metric space $(X,d)$" could have a narrower meaning, because some particular codomain might be implied.  It might mean the codomain is also $(X,d)$, so $f$ is a continuous function from $(X,d)$ to $(X,d)$.  It might mean that the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric, or $\mathbb{C}$ with the standard metric (this meaning is more likely if you say "$f_1$ is a continuous function on a metric space $(X,d)$"; the word "function" is sometimes used to mean specifically real-valued or complex-valued function).

Without context, you cannot say for sure which of these meanings is intended.  My default assumption would be the most general meaning: "$f_1$ is continuous on a metric space $(X,d)$" means that $f_1$ is a continuous function from $(X,d)$ to some topological space (not necessarily a metric space).  But it all depends on context, and you should figure out from context what meaning makes sense (and not use this phrase itself unless you make the meaning clear from context).